# Flutter textform feild validation error Closure(String?)=>dynamic from Function mobileNumber static must has 10 characters

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am getting this weird error message when the mobile number is validation failed

`Closure(String?)=>dynamic from Function mobileNumber static must has 10 characters`

in this, this is the expected output `mobileNumber static must has 10 characters` but I'm getting it with this `Closure(String?)=>dynamic from Function`

i tried removing the static then I m unable to call it, this is the full code

```
static mobileNumber(String? txt) {
    if (txt == null || txt.isEmpty) {
      var mobileNumber = 'Mobile Number';
      return "Invalid $mobileNumber!";
    }
    print(txt.length);
    if (txt.length != 10) {
      return "$mobileNumber must has 10 characters";
    }
    if (!txt.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
      return "$mobileNumber must has digits";
    } else {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a variable name/scope conflict. 
You are using the same name `mobileNumber` for the function and same
name inside the function.

The inner variable 'mobileNumber' is only created inside the if statement

```
if (txt == null || txt.isEmpty) {
      var mobileNumber = 'Mobile Number';
      return "Invalid $mobileNumber!";
    }
```

Outside the if variable, mobileNumber is a function `static mobileNumber...`
Change your code to something like this

```
static mobileNumber(String? txt) {
      var mobileNumberStr = 'Mobile Number';
    if (txt == null || txt.isEmpty) {
      return "Invalid $mobileNumberStr!";
    }
    print(txt.length);
    if (txt.length != 10) {
      return "$mobileNumberStr must has 10 characters";
    }
    if (!txt.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
      return "$mobileNumberStr must has digits";
    } else {}
  }
```

Comment: yes your answer is correct thanks for the help